# Converting string into an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a string:

```
key = "41521"
```

And I want to convert it into an array like this:

```
array = [41, 15, 52, 21]
```

I went about it like so:

```
array = []
array << key[0..1].to_i
array << key[1..2].to_i
array << key[2..3].to_i
array << key[3..4].to_i
```

What would be a better way?

Comment: There are two problems with your approach. The main one is that it only works when `array` contains 4 elements. In addition, your code contains excessive repetition. For example, you could write `(0..key.size-2).each_with_object([]) { |i,array| array << key[i,2].to_i }
 #=> [41, 15, 52, 21]`. Note that [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) merely serves to eliminate the need for `array = []` at the beginning an `array` (to return the computed value of `array`) at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
key = "41521"

key.each_char.each_cons(2).map { |a| a.join.to_i }
  #=> [41, 15, 52, 21]
```

or

```
key.gsub(/\d(?=(\d))/).with_object([]) { |s,a| a << (s<<$1).to_i }
  #=> [41, 15, 52, 21]
```

or

```
a = []
e = key.each_char
  #=> #<Enumerator: "41521":each_char>
loop { a << (e.next << e.peek).to_i }
a #=> [41, 15, 52, 21]
```

In #3 [Enumerator#peek](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek) raises a `StopInteration` exception when the internal position of the enumerator is at the end (unless `key` is an empty string, in which case [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) raises the `StopInteration` exception). [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) handles the exception by breaking out of the loop.

Comment: Last one is nice. Also you could chain the loop with `with_object`.

Comment: I've noticed that you seem to have gained a fondness for enumerators.

Comment: I do enjoy your use of `next` and especially `peek`, it's very neat. I'll occasionally take a stab using said methods but I definitely wouldn't have thought to use them here.

Comment: How does the loop terminate exactly?

Comment: @Sagar, I added an answer to your question to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
key.gsub(/(?<=.)\d(?=.)/, '\&\&').scan(/\d{2}/).map(&:to_i)
# => [41, 15, 52, 21]
```

or

```
(0...key.length).map{|i| key[i, 2].to_i}
# => [41, 15, 52, 21, 1]
```

Comment: Don't you want `0...key.length-1`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes, though `length-2` should be correct and I really like that solution

Comment: @vol7ron, note that sawa has used three dots for the range.

Answer (score 1):

Not as short as some other answers, but for me, more easier to see the steps:

```
arr = key.chars.each_with_index
         .reduce([]) {|s,(v,i)| s << (v + (key[i+1] || '')).to_i }
         .select {|s| s.to_s.length > 1 }

# arr: [41, 15, 52, 21]
```

Comment: You can use `chars` instead of `split('')`. Or even `each_chars`.

Comment: Thanks Sagar (ruby is not my forte) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
(0..(key.length-2)).map{|i| key.slice(i, 2)}
```

Comment: add a `.to_i` in there

Comment: Hieu, @Phlip meant that you need to write `key.slice(i,2).to_i`, as an array of integers is desired.